# Custom filter for grid view not working (two associated models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gridview, associations

I am using `wice_grid` and have two associated tables: Organization and User (with a 1:many relationship). For a grid view of all users I would like to include a column which states the name of the organization that the user belongs to (a variable in the organization model). To this end, I defined a custom filter, for which the gem provides instructions [here](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#custom-filters-and-associations-joined-tables).

I defined the following column for the grid view:

```
g.column name: 'Organization', filter_type: :string, attribute: 'users.organization_id', 
         custom_filter: Organization.all.map{|pr| [pr.id, pr.organizationname]} do |user|
  link_to(user.organization.organizationname, organization_path(user.organization))
end
```

The error message that this generates (referring to the first line):

```
WiceGrid: Invalid attribute name users.organization_id. An attribute name must not contain a table name!
```

But I do feel I've exactly what the example in the instructions also has. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Update:** If I change the first line to:

```
g.column name: 'Organization', filter_type: :string, attribute: 'organization_id',
```

the page renders without error. However, the filter for this column is a drop-box rather then a search field for a string (changing it to `filter_type: :string` has no effect). In addition, if I try to sort the column, the page gives the error below. Any ideas how to define the column/custom filter?

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Gutmann-Stroman 95"
LINE 1: ...OM "users" WHERE (( users.organization_id = 'Gutmann-S...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE (( users.organization_id = 'Gutmann-Stroman 95'))
```

`organization_id` in the user table holds the id number of the organization the user belongs to. "Gutmann-Stroman 95" is the `organizationname` associated to the id. I'm using `friendly_id` for friendly url's, which in the url converts the id's in the names; perhaps this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I do feel I've exactly what the example in the instructions also has.

Wrong. The example specifies `model: 'Project'`, and you don't. The example uses `name` of the joined table and you don't. Your code is as far away from the example as possible. Also, where in the documentation do you see `filter_type: :string` ?

You should have something like

```
g.column name: 'Organization', model: 'Organization', attribute: 'organizationname' do |user|
  link_to(
    user.organization.organizationname, 
    organization_path(user.organization)
  )
end
```

and in `initialize_grid` you need to include your assocation correctly:

```
yourgrid = initialize_grid(User,
  include:  [:organization]
)
```

Here you can see a working example: http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com/joining_tables

Comment: Thanks, the example I referred is somewhat below the one you refer to. The one that starts with ` g.column name: 'Project Name', attribute: 'tasks.project_id',`. Because I understood that the example above it “is bad style and can fail”. Anyways, I’ve now implemented as you suggested and it indeed makes much more sense this way. It did indeed work for my grid as in my original post! Great!

Comment: Couldn’t get it to work for another associated grid: Prizes `has many` Organizations. In the Prizes grid I would like a column: `prize.organizations.count.to_s`. I included `include: [:organization]` in `initialize_grid`. `g.column name: 'Count', model: 'Organization', attribute: 'prize_id' do |prize|` `prize.organizations.count.to_s` `end`. Error: `Association named 'organization' was not found on Prize`. The thing is that Prize has no column for organizations; the organization’s table has a column with the id of the prize (if any) that the organization is associated with.

Comment: My mistake was `include: [:organization]` should be `include: [:organizations]`.